# Bootstrap, getting two elements to swap sides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, css-float

I'm building a website for the first time in a while — and it seems Bootstrap has changed a fair bit since I last used it.

So I have two divs like so:

```
<div class="one col-lg-6">
    <p>One</p>
</div>

<div class="two col-lg-6">
    <p>Two</p>
</div>
```

So `Two` would of course display as the right-hand column

Previously, if I wanted to get them to switch sides, I'd simple float 'One' to the right and 'Two' to the left.

But that no longer appears to work (something to do with Flexbox I think?)... and I read that setting auto margins can be used instead of floating elements.

However, I've tried the following and both divs remain as they are:

```
.one {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.two {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Is there a workaround for this without having to change the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a solution native to bootstrap but you could definitely use the `flex-direction: row-reverse;` property for this.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.row-reverse {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row row-reverse">
  <div class="one col-6">
    <p>One</p>
  </div>

  <div class="two col-6">
      <p>Two</p>
  </div>
</div>
```